# Mysterious whitespace in image div in Firefox when setting height as a percentage

Tags: html, css

Hoping someone here can help me solve this mystery I'm experiencing in Firefox with my CSS.

I'm building a horizontally scrolling photo website, and have each of my images in a div. In CSS, I'm using percentages to set both the height of the divs and the height of my images so they can be responsive. This works in Chrome and Safari exactly as I would expect, but when I tested it in Firefox I get a huge whitespace to the right of each of my images. It appears to be coming from the div (not the image itself). When I change the image height to px or to vh, the whitespace disappears, leading me to think the % is the culprit. But why? And how do I fix this?

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bpnqjesr/

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: .015em;
  color: #000000;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

a:link,
a:visited {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover,
a:active {
  color: #a9c4d4;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.navbar {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 110px;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  margin: 0px 10px;
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  font-style: italic;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

#name-link {
  color: #a9c4d4;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.selected-link {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.content {
  margin: 130px 0px 0px 120px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.text {
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 700px;
}

.project-scrolling {
  height: 80%;
}

.project-info {
  font-size: 1em;
  max-width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.project-title {
  font-size: 1.75em;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.photo-gallery {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
}

.photo-gallery img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <a href="/" id="name-link">Title</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a class="selected-link">Projects</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="/travelogue">P1</a>
      <a href="/present-ruin">P2</a>
      <a href="/flight-patterns" class="selected-link">P3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="/about">About</a>
  <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
</nav>
<div class="content">
  <div class="project-scrolling">
    <div class="project-info">
      <p class="project-title">Project Title</p>
    </div>
    <div class="photo-gallery"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300?text=IMAGE%201" /></div>
    <div class="photo-gallery"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300?text=IMAGE%201" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your fiddle would illustrate the issue a lot better, if it had images in it that actually load …

Comment: And even when I put two placeholder images into it, like so, https://jsfiddle.net/96vcfgn7/, I am still not sure where the actual issue is supposed to be now.

Comment: Please change the snippet I made you to a [mcve] because we do no actually understand the issue. Perhaps you can make a drawing too?

Comment: I've run this in both Firefox and Chrome and there is no difference between the output

Comment: Whatever you are trying to achieve by splashing percentage heights on all those elements, probably won’t do what you wanted to begin with. A height in percentage needs the parent element to have a definitive height. You have `.photo-gallery` set to 100% of the parent, which is in turn set to 80% of parent `.project-scrolling` - but the parent of that, `.content`, does not have a deterministic height, but in turn gets its height from its content, so the whole thing starts to crumble at that point. […]

Comment: […] With two images of different intrinsic heights, you can clearly see that both of your `.photo-gallery` elements did not actually get the same height. Maybe time you looked into some modern layout mechanism like flexbox or grid?

Comment: `display: inline-block;`